# Lighting per polygon

Tags: rendering, light

Is there a way for an object to be rendered with a one tone lighting?
When I render a low poly object, it is illuminated with a lighting gradient -

[image]

What I need is one tone lighting on each polygon, where the lighting quality is highly depended on the poly detail of the object - lighting per polygon instead of lighting per pixel. Which means that every polygon would be illuminated by a one tone of lighting so that the pixels on each polygon are equally colored -

[image]

Is that possible to achieve and possibly in Cycles too?

Comment: What about flat shading?

Comment: That's the term I was gonna use, but its one of those things when I just can't remember. I'll make an update. How to do it?

Comment: But would flat shading work in your case? http://www.pasteall.org/pic/77631

Comment: Of course. I have low poly models that would be rendered without the need of that gradient like shading. And that possible to do in Cycles?

Comment: Cycles supports flat shading... Primitives are flat shaded by default.

Comment: The point is about the light casting on the object in the render. I made an update.

Comment: What about using OpenGL viewport render and a sun lamp in textured viewport shading (using flat shading/Blender Render(or Game)+GLSL)? Can't think of an easy way to achieve per face lighting in BI/Cycles right now... [example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5DXvrt8x04CU3lycE9ibHFsN0E/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @user2859 Thanks for the suggestion. I'm aiming for an actual render with the shadows in play and possible light bouncing (cycles) and GLSL does not block the light from lighting other objects.

Comment: Ahh, ok. Well.. shadows are somewhat supported [example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5DXvrt8x04CczFFdGtkejRuTU0/edit?usp=sharing). Bounce light would need some custom glsl code though. I thought you where looking for oldschool flat shading, where a face has constant color distribution.

Comment: heh, it looks like you thought it good. Basically, if the color of the polygon was depended of the light, then that polygon is equally colored (lighting per polygon instead of lighting per pixel).

Comment: You might be best off doing this in the compositor somehow.

Comment: There are tutorials on that, but the main purpose is to reduse the render times, because light calculations would be faster, I think. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If your goal is to reduce rendertimes, I think other things things can be done which will affect the visual result less. It depends on your particular case though..